# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and Finite Sets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $F : [a, b] \rightarrow R$ is continuous and differentiable on $[a, b]$ \ $S$, where $S$ is a finite set. Suppose there exists an $f ∈R[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=F′(x)$ for $x∈[a,b]$\ $S$. Show that $\int_a^b f = F(b)−F(a)$.

How would the proof of this be different from the proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: The hypothesis is a bit unclear. I presume we're assuming $F$ is continuous on *all* of $[a,b]$ and may only fail to be  differentiable at points of $S$?

Comment: The only information I was given is what I have written...

Comment: What is $R[a,b]$?

Comment: Continuing Ted Shifrin's comment: If $F$ isn't required to be continuous on all of $[a,b]$, then the desired conclusion doesn't follow. So it's important whether the assumption means "continuous and (differentiable on $[a,b]\setminus S$)", which works, or "(continuous and differntiable) on $[a,b]\setminus S$", which doesn't. Fortunately, the latter reading is unlikely when one realizes that "continuous" would be redundant in the presence of "diffrerentiable".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $S$ as $S =\{x_1, x_2, x_n\}$ and let $a < x_1 < x_2 < \dots , x_n < b$. Now divide the interval $[a,b]$ into finite number of subintervals as follows $[a , x_1], [x_1 , x_2], \dots ,[x_n , b]$ Now $f$ satisfies all the conditions of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in each of the intervals.

1. $f$ is integrable in each of the sub-intervals.
2. Anti-derivative of the function $f$ i.e. $F$ exists in each of the sub-intervals.

Now apply the Fundamental Theorem separately.

$$\int_a^{x_1}f(x)dx = F(x_1) - F(a)$$
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)dx = F(x_2) - F(x_1)$$
and at last 
$$\int_{x_n}^{b}f(x)dx = F(b) - F(x_n)$$

Add all of them and apply this following for logical completion

If we remove a finite number of points from the domain of the definition of the function to be integrated , then the value of the integral will be same as the previous one

So you shall get 
$$\int_a^{b}f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)$$

For more lengthy proof you may show that the Fundamental Theorem is valid in each of the subintervals.